# PHP file linked to MYSQL will not open: Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli" not found

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to open the PHP file linked to MySQL, but the following error keeps appearing.
I've already deleted the ";" before "extension=mysqli" from the pp-ini file, and then I've re-executed my computer, but it still doesn't work.
Does anyone know the solution?

[image]

[image]

1. Already removed the annotation of "extended-mysqli" in "php.ini-production file".
2. Hope the php linked to mysql works properly.

Comment: Please run ```php -v``` and let me now your version of php, because you might need to write mysql for older versions of php, PHP<5.0

Comment: php only recognizes php.ini. whatever "php.ini-production", "php.ini-fun", "php.ini-playground" are ignored. You are supposed to rename one of the prebuilt template ini files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but My php version is PHP Version 8.2.10.

Comment: Where did you get that "extension=C:\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll"  from the comment below? it was `extension=mysqli` only yesterday

Answer (score -1):

You will need to make sure that the extension is enabled in the php.ini which is actually being used, you install the extension on your operating system for the PHP you use and you restart your webserver before you test.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But In my case, there is no "php.ini" file so I make it from "php.ini-development". After that, I activated "extension=C:\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll" by removing the annotation.  And then when I start over, I still run into the same problem. If anyone knows any other way than this, I would really appreciate it if you could answer.